# VLC 3.0.8 Top menu bar is missing on Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, vlc, interface

Running Adapta theme, and a fresh 18.04 install the top menu bar seems to be missing. The "minimal view" in tools > preferences only removes the bottom bar.

[image: VLC without menu]

How do I add the top menu back (with file, tools...)

Comment: I do not see this as a Ubuntu question I see this as a VLC settings issue. https://www.videolan.org/support/

Comment: Only happening on Ubuntu it seems, related to the ubuntu presentation of VLC, possibly related to the Ubuntu theming and how it handles the top menu bar

Comment: I do not have that issue in 18.04 or 20.04.

Comment: @dave what appearance theme are you using? Also are you using apt or snap vlc and what version?

Comment: Default I do not play with that stuff. It was an apt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt remove indicator-applet-appmenu` did the trick, menu is back.